# python (onnx) cannot import name X

Tags: python, python-3.x, caffe2

System info:
Ubuntu 16.04

Python 3.6.5 in `anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/bin/python3`

Anaconda3 4.5.2

CPU only

I installed Caffe2 by `conda install -c caffe2 caffe2`
for python to find onnx i set the PYTHONPATH to `/home/username/WorkStuff/anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/lib/python3.6/site-packages/caffe2/python`

importing onnx `import onnx` in python works fine, but when i tried to run converter script provided in  [tutorial](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/Caffe2OnnxExport.ipynb) i get this:

```
File "converter.py", line 2, in <module>
import caffe2.python.onnx.frontend
File "/home/username/WorkStuff/anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/caffe2/python/onnx/frontend.py", line 22, in <module>
from onnx import (defs, checker, helper, numpy_helper, mapping,
File "/home/username/WorkStuff/anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/caffe2/python/onnx/helper.py", line 9, in <module>
from onnx.backend.base import namedtupledict
File "/home/username/WorkStuff/anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/caffe2/python/onnx/backend.py", line 33, in <module>
from onnx import checker, GraphProto, TensorProto, AttributeProto, 
ModelProto
ImportError: cannot import name 'checker'
```

checker.h is located in `/home/username/WorkStuff/anaconda3/envs/testcaffe/include/onnx`
although there are no ...Proto files in my testcaffe directory

if i just run Python and write import onnx.checker it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onnx.checker'`

seems like onnx cant import any of its modules

Is there anything i simply miss or don't understand?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the newer version of ONNX does not have these files.

I tested ONNX v1.0.0 and everything is there.
Please install it by using: `conda install -c willyd onnx`

This works on linux x64, but I'm not sure how to fix on other systems.